# Global EventBus in GoLang

Tags: go

I am trying to learn GO and in doing so trying different concepts. Right now I am trying a PubSub approach, but within the application. I have an [EventBus](https://github.com/asaskevich/EventBus) and I amd trying to pass the instance via Dependency Injection. However when I run the application nothing happens.

main

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/asaskevich/EventBus"
    modelA "interfaces/internal/modelA"
    modelB "interfaces/internal/modelB"
)

func main() {
    bus := EventBus.New()

    a := &modelA.Bus{EventBus: bus}
    a.Send()

    b := &modelB.Bus{
        EventBus: bus,
    }
    b.Receive()

}
```

internal/modelA

```
package modelA

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/asaskevich/EventBus"
)

type Bus struct {
    EventBus EventBus.Bus
}

type ModelAService interface {
    Run()
    Send()
}

func calculator(a int, b int) {
    fmt.Printf("ModelA "+"%d\n", a+b)
}

func (bus *Bus) Receive() {
    err := bus.EventBus.Subscribe("testMessageFromB", calculator)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error Receiving message...")
    }
}

func (bus *Bus) Send() {
    bus.EventBus.Publish("testMessageFromA", 33, 33)
}
```

internal/modelB

```
package modelB

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/asaskevich/EventBus"
)

type Bus struct {
    EventBus EventBus.Bus
}

type ModelBService interface {
    Run()
    Send()
}

func calculator(a int, b int) {
    fmt.Printf("ModelB "+"%d\n", a+b)
}

func (bus *Bus) Receive() {
    err := bus.EventBus.Subscribe("testMessageFromA", calculator)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error Receiving message...")
    }
}

func (bus *Bus) Send() {
    bus.EventBus.Publish("testMessageFromB", 33, 60)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first **Subscribe** to a topic
then **Publish** (executes callback defined for a topic).

Try something like this:

```
func main() {
    bus := EventBus.New()

    a := &modelA.Bus{EventBus: bus}
    b := &modelB.Bus{EventBus: bus}

    b.Receive() // Subscribe
    a.Send()    // Publish
    // Unsubscribe
}
```

Also see the [example](https://github.com/asaskevich/EventBus#example):

```
func calculator(a int, b int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", a + b)
}

func main() {
    bus := EventBus.New();
    bus.Subscribe("main:calculator", calculator);
    bus.Publish("main:calculator", 20, 40);
    bus.Unsubscribe("main:calculator", calculator);
}
```

My debugging structure and output:
[image]

---

Footnotes:
You may rename `b.Receive()` to  `b.Subscribe()`
and `a.Send()` to `a.Publish()` for clarity.

See also [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/):

[image]